# Mac Pro with Startup Security Utility

Tags: macos, command-line, disk-utility, security, t2

hi I am trying to remove or disable Startup Security Utility in terminal, does anyone know any commands that can do this so I can reinstall from an external device, for some reason internet recovery is not working. I can get into terminal.

Comment: It sounds like a firmware password has been set and you don't know the password. In that case, see below:

https://support.apple.com//HT204455

Comment: The Apple page on Startup Security Utility https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198. Does that help or explain?

Answer (score 0):

The tool you seek to bypass is embedded in firmware so it’s not going to be trivial to trick or bypass.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

Have you tried reaching out to Apple for assistance in releasing the firmware lock? They typically need proof of the original purchase to help with this task. Store visit is not required in most cases now for this fix and you can surely start the support ticket remotely.

Comment: "Store visit is not required." You mean Apple can release a firmware lock remotely..?

Comment: Yes @benwiggy they have a process to send this remotely now.

Comment: That assumes you've got the Wifi up and running, though? And even so, I'm curious how they can 'target' any given Mac in the world.

Comment: My hunch would be they generate a cryptographic key that’s targeted for the Secure Enclave which entwines the serial number and other hardware identifiers based on keys installed in the factory and serialized components when it was assembled, but I haven’t had to do this process for the last 10 years, myself. I don’t know if they wipe the device remotely or get the user to install software / net boot via internet, so there’s a lot I can’t answer technically.